# How use awk to print if a column value has even number

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, logs

I have an access log file with different port numbers in column 2. I want to list all traffic which went through even numbered ports. How can I do it?

Comment: Add an example chunk and your desired output from that.

Answer (score 3):

No expert in `awk`, but here's a simple example of using the modulus operator:

```
echo "foo bar 2
bar foo 3
foobar barfoo 4" | awk '($3 %2 == 0)'
foo bar 2
foobar barfoo 4
```

Only the lines where `$3` is **even** is printed.

Answer (score 1):

if your log file is like below:

```
cat logfile

192.168.1.102 81 [15/Aug/2016:10:52:32 +0530] "some message"
192.168.1.101 8888 [15/Aug/2016:10:52:32 +0530] "some message"
192.168.1.103 80 [15/Aug/2016:10:53:33 +0530] "some message"
192.168.1.102 2323 [15/Aug/2016:10:54:32 +0530] "some message"
```

then you can print complete line of log message which have even port number using below command:

```
while read line; do if [ $((`echo "$line"|awk '{ print $2 }'` % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then echo "$line"; fi ; done < "logfile"
```

which will produce output like:

```
while read line; do if [ $((`echo "$line"|awk '{ print $2 }'` % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then echo "$line"; fi ; done < "logfile"
192.168.1.101 8888 [15/Aug/2016:10:52:32 +0530] "some message"
192.168.1.103 80 [15/Aug/2016:10:53:33 +0530] "some message"
```

OR

if you want to print only port no then you can do like:

```
for i in `cat logfile | awk '{ print $2 }'`; do if [ $(($i % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then echo "Port number: $i"; fi ; done

Port number: 8888
Port number: 80
```

**Note:** i am assuming you don't have blank line in your log file.

Comment: this look very complicated, why not use  `awk '$2 % 2 == 0 ' logfile`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the file format that you use (delimiter space, comma, pipe, etc):

```
cat <filename> | awk -F"<delimiter>" '{if ($<column number> %2 == 0){print $0}}'
```

Sample file that I have created as below :

```
/ : server1> cat test1
a 2
b 1
c 5
d 6
e 9
f 8
```

I will perform query as below to get desired output :

```
/ : server1> cat test1 | awk -F" " '{if ($2 %2 == 0){print $0}}'
a 2
d 6
f 8
```

Comment: You dont really need the `if` and `print`, a simple `'($2 %2 == 0)'` will suffice.

Comment: Hi @maulinglawns, noted on this, reason i used print method is in case if one wants to print only certain column, they can print it this way. Example, if they want to print column 1 and column 3 upon hitting even number port, they can use like this to display what they want : {print $1","$3}